# PHP Can the order of array elements (as initialized) be counted on as a behavior?

Tags: php

I'm using numeric keys that are part of my data, if I can count on the order as initialized my solution is easier, friendlier to read, and cleaner code!

Probably obvious but: Between array initialization and the `foreach()` outputting the data no other array functions will be touching the array.

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what you're talking about

Comment: yeah and too bad image trolling is not possible xD

Comment: I thought the answer was jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP arrays are implemented as hashes. Even for numeric keys, the keys actually exist and values are associated with them, unlike lists or sets in other languages. You can count on the order to never change on its own, because that would mean actually changing the values associated with the (numeric) keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can count on it. PHP only changes the order after a `sort()` or similar function call.

You could have found out by `var_dump()`ing the array yourself, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if:

```
array("a","b","c")
```

will always put a into key 1, b into key 2, and c into key 3, then yes, it can be counted on (hence the name array).

Comment: @Radu In what programming language is there a construct of an array that is not absolutely ordered and numbered according to that order?

Comment: Any language that uses [sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for example. Sets are not guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: @Radu A set is not an array. Technically, I guess a PHP `array` is more of a sorted map than an array, but my point about array stands.